# JMeter: Plugins manager does not show any update in Options > Plugins Manager in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, plugins, jmeter, installation

I could successfully install **plugins-manager.jar** in my Windows system after keeping  **plugins-manager.jar** file in JMeter_path/lib/ext but in Ubuntu, **Options > Plugins Manager** does not show that it has any upgrades available and hence I am not able to utilize 3rd party listeners in JMeter.

Please help.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue may be related to proxy configuration on ubuntu.

Check that you can do from ubuntu:

> wget https://jmeter-plugins.org/

or

> curl https://jmeter-plugins.org/

See:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server
- https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/#Using-Behind-the-Proxy

Answer (score 2):

To get Plugin Manager option in JMeter.

1. Download jar from link: [Plugin Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/install/Install/)
2. Paste above jar into JMeter downloaded directory on this path: `apache-jmeter-5.1.1/lib/ext`
3. Restart JMeter.